# Using Crontab - some clarification

Tags: cron

I have a rake task which runs as per the following values, using certain format fields(given below values):-

**Value 1:**

30   0   */1   *   *

**Format Fields:**

1    2    3   4   5
hrs min  d/m  m   d/w

Here we have, d - day; m -month; w - week.

When I tried to better understand this, it basically meant that it would be at 00:30 hrs every day a week and every week of the month.

I'm only not clear about what does the third field d/m refer to wrt */1.

As in, I am unable to figure out the difference wrt the above value and another value say:-

**Value 2:**

30 0 1 * *

Do the both basically refer to the same period of execution on a timely basis?

Kindly advice me on this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field order is

```
min hour day month weekday
```

So

```
30 0 */1 * *
```

sets minutes to 30, hour to 0, and day to every day.  This is a *daily* task that runs at 00:30 (or 12:30 AM) every day of the month.  It is equivalent to

```
30 0 * * *
```

since the step value of `/1` is superfluous.

In contrast,

```
30 0 1 * *
```

sets minutes to 30 and hour to 0 as before but sets day to 1.  This is a *monthly* task that runs at 00:30 (12:30 AM) on the 1st day of every month.

Comment: Thanks, I got the difference..:)